# VBA error handling if string not found in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have code looking for "Model" in a column in excel but sometimes the work "Model" will not be there. Is there a way to error handle this? Basically I want it to say "if Model is not there then do xxx"

```
bNotModelType = True
checking_type = "ModelType"
Do While bNotModelType
    If Cells(j, 1).Value = checking_type Then
        Model_Type_Row = j
        bNotModelType = False
    End If
    j = j + 1
    If Model_Type_Row = Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("NADA")
Loop
```

I have an incorrect use of Nothing

UPDATE:

I ended up using:

```
lastPossibleRow = 1000000

lastRoww = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lastPossibleRow).End(xlUp).Row
j = 1

bNotModelType = True
checking_type = "ModelType"
Do While bNotModelType And j < lastRoww

    If Cells(j, 1).Value = checking_type Then
        Model_Type_Row = j
        bNotModelType = False
    Else
    j = j + 1

    End If
Loop

    If Model_Type_Row = 0 Then
        'do something
    Else
        'code for if modeltype was found in the excel document
    End If
```

I added in finding the last row because excel was running out of memory

Comment: `Model_Type_Row` looks like it is an Integer type. You can try `If Model_Type_Row = 0 Then` instead

Comment: Try to insert a break point, to inspect the value of `Model_Type_Row` or use `Debug.Print` to show the value. My guess is that it is a data type which has a different default value than `Nothing` (perhaps `""` or `0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code already supports that... you just need an else statement to your if.

```
bNotModelType = True
checking_type = "ModelType"
Do While bNotModelType
    'changing from value equals to instr so you can find partial matches
    If Instr(Cells(j, 1).Value,checking_type) Then 'InStr() this will do a boolean check if it's in the string
        Model_Type_Row = j
        bNotModelType = False
    Else 'added here
        'add your code when not met.
    End If
    j = j + 1
    'If Model_Type_Row = 0 Then MsgBox ("NADA") 'if you want within loop, do this
    'Model_Type_Row = 0
Loop
If Model_Type_Row = 0 Then MsgBox ("NADA") 'moved msgbox out of loop
```

---

**Edit1:**

Question... what is wrong with using `.Find()` on the column?

```
if iserror(Columns(1).Find(What:=checking_type, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False))
    'when there is an error, do this
    MsgBox ("NADA")
else
    'do something when the row is found
    Model_Type_Row = Columns(1).Find(What:=checking_type, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
End if
```

---

**Edit2:**

Showed moving msgbox outside of loop, per lizard6's comment.

Comment: Wouldn't `Model_Type_Row` be a Integer/Long Type? I don't think you can compare it to nothing as it isn't an object.

Comment: @RyanWildry yes; i don't see his declarations, but hopefully he has listed as Long... i was just fixing that line when you posted (he had a line break after `then`, but no end if

Comment: "If Model_Type_Row = 0 then..." needs to be outside of the loop or else the message box pops up after the first iteration

Comment: @lizard6 very true; depending on how OP wants to use it, this may be intended, similar to `FindNext` (mirrored how it appeared in the post).  To your point, `Model_Type_Row = j` would need to be set back to `0` after the msgbox (edited post to support that)

Comment: @Cyril very true I didn't think of that. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
checking_type = 0
On Error Resume Next
checking_type = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet where you are looking").Cells.Find("ModelType").Column
On Error GoTo 0
If checking_type <> 0 Then
    'code if column is found
Else
    'code if column not found
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your boolean variable to achieve the test:

```
If bNotModelType = False Then
   Msgbox
End If
```

Or use `Model_Type_Row <> 0` (then initialize it to 0 prior to looping).